# Obtain windows domain username and unique token/password to pass through service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-identity

I have an app that users would run locally on their desktop, which calls into an API on my server externally.

I can obtain the user's Windows domain and name through the `WindowsIdentity` API. But I'd like to store a unique identifier/token on our side which I can compare subsequent logins with to ensure it's the same domain user and not an impersonator.

**I cannot ask the user for credentials**, as the login process is for beginner users and they need to be automatically logged in when opening the app. I'm looking through the `WindowsIdentity` API looking for some unique ID, but not sure how it would last through password changes on the user's domain.

Edit: Perhaps a claim off the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Claims` collection might contain something useful.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark, but could you try domain and name + IP addresses/MAC addresses to confirm its the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following claim is enough to unique identify a user in an AD environment:

`http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid`

Obtain this from:

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Claims`